# Adding more than one mouse listener to a panel

Tags: java, arrays, object, mouseevent, paint

I'm trying to add more than one mouse listener to a panel, but I want them to be on the same line like this:

```
Paint.paint.addMouseListener(Shape.circle,Shape.blah);
```

Is that possible? 
I know you can do it like this instead:

```
Paint.paint.addMouseListener(Shape.circle);
Paint.paint.addMouseListener(Shape.blah);
```

And that's not too bad, but I thought it would be easier if you're not using arrays, and you can add it to the same line if it's possible. So, anyone know if this is possible? Thanks.

Comment: What is `Paint.paint`? Where does this class come from?

Comment: Why do you need it on the same line? What do arrays have to do with it? What are `Paint` and `paint`? Why do you need more than one mouse listener anyway?

Comment: Paint.paint is a jpanel. @RealSkeptic if you make objects out of arrays you can just add it on this same line like this Paint.paint.addMouseListener(Shape.circle[i]); using a for loop. I'm making mouse listeners more objected oriented so I don't have to rewrite old codes, so I can inherited the old mouse event codes add and on to it, and to do that I need more than one mouse listener for each object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `addMouseListener(...)` method that accepts more than one listener, but you can write your own utility method to do so:

```
public static void addManyMouseListeners( Component component, MouseListener... mouseListeners ) {

    if ( component != null && mouseListeners != null ) {
        for ( MouseListener mouseListener : mouseListeners ) {
            component.addMouseListener( mouseListener );
        }
    }
}
```

The varargs parameter allows you to call the method like:

```
addManyMouseListeners( Paint.paint, Shape.circle, Shape.blah );
```

And in fact add as many mouse listeners as you like. Inside the method, the varargs parameter is interpreted as an array, and you iterate on it as you would on any array.

Comment: I see. I don't get how it works, but it's a nice method to have. I'll take it. Thanks.

Comment: @Skillet Then you should read about varargs in the section "Arbitrary Number Of Arguments" in [the java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html), and about the [enhanced for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) as well.